# Use of letter spacing in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use `letterSpacing` in my `Text()`. I did it like this

```
letterSpacing = 0.7.sp
```

but when I move this value to `dimen.xml`  and using like this

```
letterSpacing = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.text_letter_spacing),
```

It giving me error on `Text()`.

**Error**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
Text(AnnotatedString, Modifier = ..., Color = ..., TextUnit = ..., FontStyle? = ..., FontWeight? = ..., FontFamily? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextDecoration? = ..., TextAlign? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextOverflow = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., Map<String, InlineTextContent> = ..., (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ..., TextStyle = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
Text(String, Modifier = ..., Color = ..., TextUnit = ..., FontStyle? = ..., FontWeight? = ..., FontFamily? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextDecoration? = ..., TextAlign? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextOverflow = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ..., TextStyle = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
```

**Image on Error**

[image]

Comment: You can't because fontSize requires TextUnit as you can see in error but dimensionResource returns Dp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks [@Thracian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457853/thracian) for guidance.

**Option 1**

I solve the problem by converting to `toSp()` because `dimensionResource` returns a value in `dp` but `letterSpacing` expects `TextUnit`.

```
val letterSpacing = with(LocalDensity.current) {
    dimensionResource(R.dimen.text_letter_spacing).toSp()
}
Text( 
    .... // more attribute here
    letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
)
```

**Option 2**

Thanks [@RobertJamison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19037473/robert-jamison) for suggestions to use `TextUnit` directly.

```
Text(
    .... // more attribute here
    letterSpacing = TextUnit(0.7F, TextUnitType.Sp) ,
)
```

we can directly use `TextUnit` in `letterSpacing`. Be careful that `TextUnit` is `ExperimentalUnitApi`.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalUnitApi::class)
```

we have to add in function of the class.

Comment: Can do with  `letterSpacing = TextUnit(0.7F, TextUnitType.Sp)` as robert mentioned

Answer (score 0):

When you move resource values to dimen.xml, it doesn't retain the unit of measure. You should try actually setting a [TextUnit](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/TextUnit) value.

Comment: Please give me example for using `TextUnit`.. Thanks